# Migrating GitBucket to another machine

Tags: git, version-control, gitbucket

I need to migrate my live GitBucket installation from one physical machine (Win7) to a different machine (Win7), **not to backup my current installation.**

I'm using version 4.18.0 with default settings and standalone app with `java -jar gitbucket.war`.

The installation is using the default H2 database and HOME directory is C:\Users\USER\.gitbucket.

Comment: Does the answer helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutdown the current GitBucket and simply copy `~/.gitbucket` to a new machine.

Comment: Works fine. But before run I had to edit `~/gitbucket.conf` and replace old computer name with the new one.